# WKWebview showing blank page when trying to load local web. How to print errors in console?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I'm trying to load a local web, but is not working, only a white screen is being displayed.

```
let zipName = webSection?.zipResource?.zipName?.lowercased() {
let zipPath = ProjectPath.path.appending(zipName.deletingPathExtension).appending(pathComponent: "index.html")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: zipPath)
//webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url) //suppossedly new method for loading local websites, but it haves same behaviour, blank screen
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

In Android, I can see in logcat which errors is generating the webview when no content is being displayed, but here in Xcode I can't see nothing in the console. How can i see which errors is giving the WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Implement webView navigation delegate in viewDidLoad

```swift
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

```swift
extension ViewController : WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: already tryed that, didn't happened, nothing printed

Comment: have you implemented navigationDelegate in viewDidLoad?

Comment: yes @agha Shahriyar , i did:  webView.navigationDelegate = self there